# switch row/column of chart using c# excel interop

Tags: c#, excel, charts, excel-interop

I'm currently working on a Programm which creates reports using Excel Interop. Therefore I intend to create a Line Chart as followed:

[image: desired Output]

As one can see here I have a clear development of num and denom in relation to Milestones. When I select my values as chartRange manually in Excel I recieve this Diagramm. However, when do it programmatically (select exactly the same range) I get this:

[image: current output]

Well, you can see the data selected. Excel (or something I don't know about) fails to recognize the Milestones row as axis. When I right click on the Diagramm --> select data --> Change rows/columns I get my right Chart.

Now does anybody know an order to switch those rows/columns or some way to define ranges for each of the axis?

I attached the relevant part of my code here:

```
        Excel.Application myExcelApplication;
        Excel.Workbook myExcelWorkbook;

        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        myExcelApplication = null;
        myExcelApplication = new Excel.Application();
        myExcelApplication.Visible = true;
        myExcelApplication.ScreenUpdating = true;

        myExcelWorkbook = (Excel.Workbook)(myExcelApplication.Workbooks.Add(misValue));

Excel.Worksheet newWorksheet;
            newWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)myExcelApplication.Worksheets.Add();
            newWorksheet.Name = requestedVehicles[m];
            newWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)myExcelWorkbook.ActiveSheet;

            Excel.Range chartRange = myExcelApplication.get_Range("B2", endrange + 4);

            Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)newWorksheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
            Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(100, 20, 500, 400);
            Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
            chartPage.HasTitle = true;
            chartPage.ChartTitle.Text = "num/denom";
            chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, Excel.XlRowCol.xlColumns);
            chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlXYScatterLines;
```

Thanks in advance,
Andy

Answer (score 1):

hmmm, if the proposed solution does not work for all, this is how you can do it directly from the interop; use the method `ChartWizard()`, the parameter `PlotBy` does the trick.

This is how I use it:

```
wsChart.ChartWizard(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlRowCol.xlRows, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Here is the doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._chart.chartwizard?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Chart.ChartWizard);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=excel-pia

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself due to this post I've stumbled across:
https://www.codeproject.com/questions/870177/csharp-excel-chart-x-axis-category-labels

The Problem was that the upper left cell of my defined range wasn't empty.. so Excel assumed it was supposed to be a data series.